# Replace a value in pytorch tensor

Tags: pytorch

```
t=tensor([0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6])
```

now i need to modify this existing tensor t as follows:

```
t=tensor([0.1 0.2 0.7 0.4 0.8 0.6])
```

I tried as follows:

```
t=tensor([0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6])
a=tensor([0.1 0.2 0.7 0.4 0.8 0.6])
index=range(len(a))
t.index_copy_(0,index,a)
```

But still it is not updating
how can i modify the tensor in pytorch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
t = tensor([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6])
t.index_copy_(0, tensor([2, 4]), tensor([0.7, 0.8]))
```

Reference:

[torch.Tensor.index_copy_](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.Tensor.index_copy_.html)

Comment: Still I'm unable to update it

Comment: Please share your full code in your question, maybe there is something that is done wrong..

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/95027/pytorch-dataloader-tensor-modification I would like to update tensor which is in dataloader may be because of that i'm unable to update i guess