# pytorch dataloader tensor modification

Tags: pytorch

```
T=tensor([101,123,414,463][234,903,313,341]...)
train=TensorDataset(T)
train_dataloader=Dataloader(train)
```

Now I would like to update tensor `T[0]` i.e tensor

```
T[0]=tensor([101,123,567,463])
```

for this i have tried as follows:

```
train_dataloader.Dataset[0].index_copy_(0,tensor([2]),tensor([567])
```

is it possible to modify this way or not?
Any kind of reference is helpful

Comment: If I am not mistaken you cannot access `Dataset` by index and modify it, same as one cannot access a tensor element by index and modify it

Comment: Is their any other way to handle this

Comment: train_dataloader.Dataset[0] is giving me first row in tensor  i.e tensor([101,123,414,463])

Comment: Is it a tensor though?

Comment: yes, it is a tensor and now I would like update certain values in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pytorch DataLoader is a generator, it will generate new batches when iterated through. Hence, as per the best of my knowledge, you can only change the data on the fly. For eg, if you want to replace the first element of your dataset with second element of the datase, you can do something like -

```
T = torch.tensor(([101,123,414,463],[234,903,313,341]))
train = TensorDataset(T)
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train)

for idx,i in enumerate(train_dataloader):
  if idx == 0:
    i = i[0] # Get the first and the only instance of the batch
    i = train[1][0]
```

Otherwise, you will need to change your dataset (train variable) and then again create a dataloader for this new dataset.

Comment: Thank You @ Devashish Prasad